# GDB disass main

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, gdb

I'm doing a security project for my school.

For this project I have a binary, and I have to do 2 things, make a pseudo code of this binary and do the exploit.

To get better in **ASM**  I'm trying to do exactly the same source code in c. I have a problem with edx in the main. I have no idee how to do this in c:

```
0x080484a5 <+41>:   mov    edx,0x8048468
```

This is the full main code:

```
Dump of assembler code for function main:
0x0804847c <+0>:    push   ebp
0x0804847d <+1>:    mov    ebp,esp
0x0804847f <+3>:    and    esp,0xfffffff0
0x08048482 <+6>:    sub    esp,0x20
0x08048485 <+9>:    mov    DWORD PTR [esp],0x40
0x0804848c <+16>:   call   0x8048350 <malloc@plt>
0x08048491 <+21>:   mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x1c],eax
0x08048495 <+25>:   mov    DWORD PTR [esp],0x4
0x0804849c <+32>:   call   0x8048350 <malloc@plt>
0x080484a1 <+37>:   mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x18],eax
0x080484a5 <+41>:   mov    edx,0x8048468
0x080484aa <+46>:   mov    eax,DWORD PTR [esp+0x18]
0x080484ae <+50>:   mov    DWORD PTR [eax],edx
0x080484b0 <+52>:   mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp+0xc]
0x080484b3 <+55>:   add    eax,0x4
0x080484b6 <+58>:   mov    eax,DWORD PTR [eax]
0x080484b8 <+60>:   mov    edx,eax
0x080484ba <+62>:   mov    eax,DWORD PTR [esp+0x1c]
0x080484be <+66>:   mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x4],edx
0x080484c2 <+70>:   mov    DWORD PTR [esp],eax
0x080484c5 <+73>:   call   0x8048340 <strcpy@plt>
0x080484ca <+78>:   mov    eax,DWORD PTR [esp+0x18]
0x080484ce <+82>:   mov    eax,DWORD PTR [eax]
0x080484d0 <+84>:   call   eax
0x080484d2 <+86>:   leave
0x080484d3 <+87>:   ret
```

Can you help me to find how to do the line main + 41 please :) ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`0x8048468` is probably a pointer value based on the number.  Maybe a function pointer, because it's in the page above `0x8048350` (the PLT entry for malloc).  But maybe just a pointer to a static buffer (maybe a read-only buffer, like a string literal).

So perhaps `void *edx = "hello world";` or `void *edx = &some_function`, and then use it somehow.  C statements don't map to single asm instructions, but with un-optimized output (`gcc -O0`), each C statement does map to a contiguous block of instructions that finishes with all values in memory.  (This means you can modify C variables with a debugger and still have it "work" in un-optimized code.)

I didn't trace through the mess of store/reload that looks like un-optimized code, so I'm not sure what exactly is being done with that value after it's stored to memory in the next instruction after the mov-immediate.

Look at your compiler's asm output if you have source (`gcc -S` instead of compiling all the way to a binary and then disassemblign), or use `objdump -drwC -Mintel` to get relocation info for that value if there is any.  Or use `nm` to look for it in the symbol table.

If it is a function pointer, the disassembly for that address should make some sense.

Comment: 0x8048468 is a pointer of a function yes. I don't have nm on this linux distribution